# Redirect if firefox

Tags: firefox, redirect

If Firefox is being used, go to another URL. This doesn't work for me. What am I overlooking? Thanks.

```
function which() {
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("firefox") != -1)){
window.location.replace = "http://chasms.com"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Location.replace() is a function, not a field, use 
`window.location.replace("http://yoururl");`

What you did in your comment isn't actually an answer to your original question.

`location = 'xx'` is equivalent to `location.href = 'xx'` and is equivalent to a `location.assign('xx')` call.

On the other hand, `location.replace('xx')` has different effect from these regarding history and security behavior.

Comment: Finally got it to working with:


    <script type="text/javascript">
        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') !=-1) {
  window.location = "http://chasms.com" }
    </script>

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your condition to:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
     window.location.replace("http://chasms.com");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies but it's still not working. Tried both of your suggestions. I call it with onload = "which()";

And I've put it directly in the page with script, no function.

Don't know. Will keep trying.

Comment: You can try: `window.location.assign("http://chasms.com");` See here: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)